# AVPlayerItem throw ARC Semantic issues when running on iPad Device

Tags: ios, ipad, avplayeritem

I have a URL that contains a .mp3 audio file. I have designed my code to play the audio using AVPlayerItem. I started tested everything in Simulator. Suddenly when i run the app on my iPad device, it started throwing errors. I am not sure what the problem is. Below are the errors thrown when the app is run on iPad Device.

[image]

I am getting ARC Semantic issues. I have iOS 9.2.1 in my iPad.

Please help me.

Comment: Those are compiler errors, not runtime errors. Did you add the proper `import` statement to your `SWMeetTheStarsVideoViewController.m` file?

Comment: @Rob Yes. I have included both AVKit and AVFoundation classes in my Interface. When i try to run the app in the device, the build fails. And it runs well on iPad simulator.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes. I have added proper import statements in my interface file. #import <AVKit/AVKit.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

Comment: Nowadays you might want `@import AVKit;`, `@import AudioToolbox;`, and `@import AVFoundation;`. When you import the headers, that will give you the sort of error you describe if you haven't linked the frameworks to your project. Now, we often don't worry about that because we use the "Link Frameworks Automatically" build setting for the target in question. So, double check that setting. Worst case scenario, you can manually add these frameworks to the "Link Binary With Libraries" in the "Build Phases" for your target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After intensive searching about the solution for these kind of issues, I found that the issue was with the Xcode version. I had to remove the old Xcode and install a new Xcode app again. It started working with the freshly installed Xcode app. I am still not sure why the old Xcode app has failed to build the App but this was the solution i found. I thought i should post this as this may be useful to someone who face these kind of issues.

Note:- Before reinstalling the Xcode, I tried the following approaches which didn't work.

1. Project Clean and Build.
2. Check if the Frameworks has been linked correctly in the Project BuildPhases and BuildSettings.
3. Removing the derived data and rebuilding the app.
4. Try the forward declaration of classes and importing the classes correctly.

None of them worked except for re-installing the Xcode. Incase if someone get struck with this kind of problem, try this.